# How to convert a MySQL DB to XML?

Tags: mysql, xml

How can you convert a MySQL database to XML?
I want everythimg... data and there relation in XML schema file

how to convert from sqlyog community 8.13(free version)

Comment: Do you mean data from the table?

Comment: How exactly do you want the data to be formatted?

Comment: I want everythimg... data and there relation in  XML schema file

Answer (score 19):

```
mysqldump --xml test > test.xml
```

or

```
mysqldump -X test > test.xml
```

[mysqldump to xml](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_xml)

Answer (score 8):

[phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net) has an Export to XML function in it. You could either use that, or examine the code to see how they did it.

Answer (score 4):

The command line client that comes with MySQL has a --xml option:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_xml

If the output format of that does not match what you need, you could just select the data out and concatenate it with your xml tags:

```
select concat('<field1>',field1,'</field1><field2>',field2,
'</field2>') from table
```

Answer (score 1):

SQLyog also does a good implementation of exporting data to XML...

Comment: Right click on table and select "Backup/Export" and choose "Export table data as..."
You can choose CSV, HTML, XML, Excel XML or SQL...
Very handy

Answer (score 1):

For a single table

```
mysql --xml -u username -p database_name table_name > table_name.xml
```

For a query

```
mysql --xml -u username -p database_name -e 'select * from table_name' > query.xml
```

For the whole database

```
mysqldump --xml -u username -p database_name > database.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

in fact it's actually

```
mysqldump --xml dbname -t tablename
```

with eventually -u username -pPASSWORD (or -p for an interactive passwd input)
according to your privileges..