# Add AND statement to WHERE clause in FETCH XML?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, fetchxml

We have this below fetchXML, I have a quick question wondering how I add this and statement to the WHERE clause:
`and ip.pcssu_quantityavailable >= sod.quantity - sod.quantityshipped` to the fetchXML?

```
<fetch mapping="logical" version="1.0">
  <entity name="SalesOrder">
    <attribute name="ordernumber" />
    <attribute name="statuscode" />
    <attribute name="statuscodename" />
    <attribute name="pcssu_stockavailable" />
    <filter>
      <condition attribute="statuscode" operator="eq" value="141560004" />
    </filter>
    <link-entity name="SalesOrderDetail" from="salesorderid" to="salesorderid" alias="sod" link-type="inner">
      <attribute name="productidname" />
      <attribute name="quantity" />
      <attribute name="quantityshipped" />
      <link-entity name="pcssu_inventoryproduct" from="pcssu_product" to="productid" alias="ip" link-type="inner">
        <attribute name="pcssu_quantityavailable" />
      </link-entity>
    </link-entity>
    <link-entity name="account" from="accountnumber" to="pcssu_servicecentrecode" alias="a" link-type="inner" />
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that FetchXml doesn't support such syntax. I'm really sorry for that. Also to make your fetch work use your entity names lowercased like salesorder and salesorderdetail (not SalesOrder and SalesOrderDetail).

Comment: To add on to what Andrii Butenko mentioned, it will be easy to create the fetch xml from advanced find to make sure you are getting the xml as business required and less prone to errors like casing.