# Export sql data base data into xml format

Tags: mysql, xml, export

I dont know much about sql data base, so kindly request to undersatnd my problem.

I have task to store sql data to care dat base, so i am adopting the flow , i will export the data in xml format and parse it in core data base, so i am exporting data from sql data base into xml format but the format not coming upon my requirement

please look at this

```
  <table name="ex_name_details">
        <column name="exId">1</column>
        <column name="exGroupId">3</column>
        <column name="exName">Arnold Press</column>
 </table>
```

i am getting the above sample

but i need this in this formatt

```
 <ex_name_details>
    <exId>1</exId>
    <exGroupId>3</exGroupId>
    <exName>Arnold Press</exName>
```

i need this sample formatt .

Using PhpMyAdmin

its a sample but, i need to parse huge data, so please help

i should ask this question in other expert area but, i have full faith on you friends .

please  answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate.... This post is some what similar:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420205/how-to-convert-a-mysql-db-to-xml

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `xsl` transformations

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
<table name="ex_name_details">
  <column name="exId">1</column>
  <column name="exGroupId">3</column>
  <column name="exName">Arnold Press</column>
</table>
```

and the xsl file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//table">
      <xsl:element name="{@name}">
        <xsl:for-each select="column">
          <xsl:element name="{@name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: will it not possible through phpmyadmin data base through any process, so i can get data without the structural tag of sql table please, my friend done this before but he is not here now

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by manipulating my MySQL database not through phpmyadmin but through MySQL Workbench application, and using Export option as XML (not mysql XML). Works reasonably fine.