# How export an Entity-Relationship Model to XML

Tags: java, mysql, xml, entity-relationship

I created one database that I need to my software, but it's a "one-way database" - I just need insert manually the data and, after that, just need read this database in the distributed client (it's called "Production environment", no?).

Because I will distribute this software on the internet, I don't want need a MySQL Server running on the user machine. I think I can solve this using XML, but I don't know anything of XML. So, how I can export my Entity-relationship (ER) model created on MySql Workbench to XML?

---

**"Bonus questions":**

By the way, have some good CRUD library for XML, in Java? If not, have a good library for writing, reading and updating an XML, in Java?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420205/how-to-convert-a-mysql-db-to-xml) solved my problem.

> mysqldump --xml test > test.xml or
>
> mysqldump -X test > test.xml

[mysqldump to xml](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option%5Fmysqldump%5Fxml)

Thanks and good luck in your project.