# Sql to JSON/XML

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, xml, json

I need to convert a big sql file into XML or JSON. Is there a specific program to execute this operation? I really don't know much about Databases or the methods used to make these kind of operations so I would be very thankful for any help provided.

Here is a sample of the start of the sql file:

```
# Dump of table auth_group_permissions
# ------------------------------------------------------------

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `auth_group_permissions`;

CREATE TABLE `auth_group_permissions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `permission_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `group_id` (`group_id`,`permission_id`),
  KEY `auth_group_permissions_bda51c3c` (`group_id`),
  KEY `auth_group_permissions_1e014c8f` (`permission_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `group_id_refs_id_3cea63fe` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `auth_group` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `permission_id_refs_id_a7792de1` FOREIGN KEY (`permission_id`) REFERENCES `auth_permission` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

LOCK TABLES `auth_group_permissions` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `auth_group_permissions` DISABLE KEYS */;

INSERT INTO `auth_group_permissions` (`id`, `group_id`, `permission_id`)
VALUES
    (65,1,8),
    (69,1,25),
    (70,1,26),
    (71,1,27),
    (72,1,28),
    (73,1,29),
```

Here is a sample from the middle:

```
(1953,'Duas Quintas Reserva','duas-quintas-reserva',34,1,1,'2013-04-20 19:24:16','2013-04-20 19:24:16',1,NULL,0,1953,NULL,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
    (1954,'Duas Quintas Reserva','duas-quintas-reserva',34,1,1,'2013-04-20 19:24:16','2013-04-20 19:24:16',1,NULL,0,1954,NULL,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
    (1955,'Duas Quintas Reserva','duas-quintas-reserva',34,1,1,'2013-04-20 19:24:16','2013-04-20 19:24:16',1,NULL,0,1955,NULL,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
    (1956,'Duas Quintas Reserva','duas-quintas-reserva',34,1,1,'2013-04-20 19:24:16','2013-04-20 19:24:16',1,NULL,0,1956,NULL,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
    (1957,'Duas Quintas Reserva','duas-quintas-reserva',34,1,1,'2013-04-20 19:24:16','2013-04-20 19:24:16',1,NULL,0,1957,NULL,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
```

Any question just ask I'm always around.

Best Regards.

Comment: Do you mean converting mysql results into the json format?  If so, what server side language are you using?

Comment: its not the results of a query, its and entire sql file, I want to convert it to a xml file :)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420205/how-to-convert-a-mysql-db-to-xml