# Exporting data from database to xml

Tags: php, mysql, xml, export-to-xml

I need to save data from a relational database record set in MySQL (composed of multiple tables and multiple sub-records for each master record) to an xml file.  My questions are:

1. Is there an xml standard format for defining the relation between the database structure and the xml to output?
2. Are there recommended open-source libraries in PHP that would do the job?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a MySQL DB to XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420205/how-to-convert-a-mysql-db-to-xml)

Comment: not the same question -- I need to export specific data into a more specific format -- not exporting the entire db, as the linked question states.  Additionally, my question asks if there is a meta-xml format to define the relation between the data from the db and the output xml format.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112282/get-mysql-database-output-via-php-to-xml does this help?

Comment: Better, but the question/answers are still a matter of hard-coding the conversion of the sql data to the xml format.  My goal is to get an xml standard of flexibly doing this.

Comment: could you edit the question and be more specific. Maybe give some sample input and output?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/XML/RDB.html and with *id* and *ref* you can model of relations in XML: http://www.w3.org/XML/Datamodel.html

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to export and import XML data using the mysql monitor.

```
$ mysql -uroot -p --xml -e 'SELECT * FROM tablename' > /tmp/tabllename.xml
```

The mysql monitor has an --xml option, which enables us to dump data in XML format. The -e option executes a statement and quits the monitor.

For whole database you can use mysqldump tool

```
mysqldump --xml databasename > databasename.xml  
  or
```

`mysqldump -X databasename> databasename.xml`

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thanx, but I need something a bit more flexible.

I have  a specific format of xml, and the record set I am dealing with consists of multiple tables.  Something like:
<pre><code>
    <record>
     <field1>value1</field1>
     <field2>value2</field2>
     ...
     <subrecord>
      <field_x>value_x</field_x>
      <field_y>value_y</field_y>
     </subrecord>
     <subrecord>
      <field_x>value_x</field_x>
      <field_y>value_y</field_y>
     </subrecord>
    </record>
</code></pre>